# Using SQLAlchemy how do I get last Inventory entry with distinct values for Product and Warehouse

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to build a simple inventory app and cannot figure out how to perform a few queries. The relevant classes are Product, Warehouse and Inventory. Product and Warehouse are pretty self-explanatory. Inventory is an association table with two extra data columns - Date (date in which inventory was done) and Quantity (number of units).

```
class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    inventories = db.relationship('Inventory', foreign_keys=[Inventory.product_id],
                                  backref=db.backref('product', lazy='joined'),
                                  lazy='dynamic', cascade='all, delete-orphan')

class Warehouse(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'warehouses'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    inventories = db.relationship('Inventory', foreign_keys=[Inventory.warehouse_id],
                                  backref=db.backref('warehouse', lazy='joined'),
                                  lazy='dynamic', cascade='all, delete-orphan')


class Inventory(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'inventories'
    warehouse_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('warehouses.id'), primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('products.id'), primary_key=True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True),
                           nullable=False, default=dt.datetime.utcnow, primary_key=True)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I would like to get this data: Product.name, Inventory.quantity, Warehouse.name, Inventory.created_at - Inventory should be the latest row based on date for each product at each warehouse.

I can join the tables, but cannot figure out how to keep just the data I am looking for without doing multiple for loops and multiple queries. The end result is to produce an HTML table such as this:

```
Product Warehouse1  Warehouse2  Total   Date
======= ==========  ==========  =====   ====    
product1    10          3         13    mm-dd-yy    
product2    11          24        35    mm-dd-yy
```

I ran flask profiler for my implementation and van's below to see what the difference was and on average van's implementation is 3X faster than the multiple sql queries and for loops I had at first.

Comment: First, I will rather use "quantity" instead of "count", because count is a reserved word and introduce confusion. Second. what if Product 1 has different entry date in Warehouse 1 and warehouse 2? E.g. Product 1 , qty 20, warehouse 1  2016-01-01;  Product 1 , qty 50 , warehouse 2 ,2016-01-02 ?

Comment: quantity vs count - Good point, I will fix that in my code. The Inventory.created_at reflects the time the Inventory was created for that specific Product at that specific Warehouse, and so there is no reason for an Inventory entry to have the same date/time across multiple Warehouses.... I expect them to be different and that is OK.  If I want to find the current inventory I just order by the date for a specific Product and Warehouse.

Comment: How would you like the table to look when Inventory for Product1 has been last updated at different times for different Warehouses? For example, product1 has latest update in Warehouse1 on 2016-10-31, but the latest update of its inventory in Warehouse2 is on 2016-11-01. Are those two rows?

Comment: Yes. Those would be two different rows on the Inventory table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Retrieve the data you need for the view.**

Code:

```
subq = (
    db.session
    .query(
        Inventory.product_id, Inventory.warehouse_id,
        db.func.max(Inventory.created_at).label("last_update")
    )
    .group_by(
        Inventory.product_id, Inventory.warehouse_id,
    )
).subquery("subq")

q = (
    db.session
    # .query(Inventory)
    .query(
        Product.name.label("Product"),
        Warehouse.name.label("Warehouse"),
        Inventory.quantity,
        Inventory.created_at.label("Date"),
    )
    .select_from(Inventory)
    .join(Product)
    .join(Warehouse)
    .join(subq, db.and_(
        subq.c.product_id == Inventory.product_id,
        subq.c.warehouse_id == Inventory.warehouse_id,
        subq.c.last_update == Inventory.created_at,
    ))
)
```

2. **Bring the data to the desired format.**

In order to achieve that, one need *pivot* functionality, which you can implement yourself, find a library, or use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Below is the solution using `pandas` building on top of the query `q` (see above):

```
# get data from database
df = pd.read_sql_query(q.statement, db.session.bind)

# create pivot table
pi = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index=['Product', 'Date'],
    columns=['Warehouse'],
    values=['quantity'],
    fill_value=0,
)

# reorder columns
pi.columns = pi.columns.droplevel()

# add total
pi['Total'] = pi.sum(axis=1)

# fix the order of columns
pi = pi.reset_index()
```

Then you can export the result to various outputs:

```
    # get a textual representation
    print(pi.to_string(index=False))

    # result looks like below:
    _res = """\
    Product       Date  Warehouse1  Warehouse2  Total
    Product1 2016-01-02           2           0      2
    Product1 2016-03-02           0          20     20
    Product2 2016-04-02           2           0      2
    """

    # JSON format which can be sent to a javascript client
    json = pi.to_json(orient='records')

    # even html representation which you can embed into your template
    html = pi.to_html()
```

Comment: Van, thank you for the detailed answer.  I haven't had a chance to tryout the code yet, but will do it soon.

Comment: I want a dictionary for the front-end so I took out the Date field as that didn't make sense to include (I think that is what you meant by your comment above). I did a `pi.iterrows()` to loop over each row and add it to a dictionary. I have never worked with pandas before and I don't think I am doing it "correctly". For example to extract the product name I am doing `row["Product"].tolist()[0]`, for Total: `row["Total"].tolist()[0]` and finally for warehouse counts I am looping through each warehouse as w and then `"amount": row["count"][w.name]`.  Is there a better way?

Comment: If you want to populate dictionary, just call `pi.to_dict(orient='records')`

Comment: van, you are brilliant.  Don't let anyone tell you any different.  Your answers worked perfectly and brought the time down from 150ms to 25ms. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty newbie in Python and SQLAlchemy but I can try.

If you want to populate dynamic number of columns ( In that case: Warehouses ):

You need something like pivot table.

Here [Data Science for Losers, Part 2](http://blog.brakmic.com/data-science-for-losers-part-2/) is solution with next tools and modules: pandas and numpy.

P.S. I'm not so experienced for creating example, but I'll try create it later.